# What is the correct way to use RLMResults in Swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, realm, realm-list

I had an xcode project and I was using Swift and Objective c code. Now in other Swift project I want use a function to load and manage some data from realm databases like:

```
@objc func myData(_ allData: RLMResults<RLMObject>) -> [[AnyHashable]] {
...
}
```

If I remove the @objc reference I get the error:

> Use of undeclared type 'RLMResults'

I have imported the realm sdk and sdk-swift, how can I declare this function in Swift?
What could be the error?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to remove the `@objc` reference?

Comment: Because is unnecessary in a Swift project. It was used in other project using Swift and objective-c mixed. I'm wrong? I get the same error with or without this

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are using RealmSwift since you want to remove the @objc tag and and you are talking about a "Swift Project"

`RLMResults` is used for Obj-C version only. When using RealmSwift you need to use `Results`

Below you need to replace  with the object result

```
import RealmSwift

func myData(_ allData: Results<Object>) -> [[AnyHashable]] {

}
```

> `Results` is an auto-updating container type in Realm returned from object queries.
>
> `Results` can be queried with the same predicates as `List<Element>`, and you can chain queries to further filter query results.
>   `Results` always reflect the current state of the Realm on the current thread, including during write transactions on the current thread.

More information can be found [HERE](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/Results.html)